# How is 'texcoord' used in this last sample?

Tags: glsl, webgl

Regarding the samples here:

https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-qna-how-to-import-a-heightmap-in-webgl.html

texcoord is set when the pointgrid is created

```
         const u0 = x / cellsAcross;
         const v0 = z / cellsDeep;
         const u1 = (x + 1) / cellsAcross;
         const v1 = (z + 1) / cellsDeep;
```

then passed through the vertex shader:

```
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec3 normal;
  attribute vec2 texcoord;

  uniform mat4 projection;
  uniform mat4 modelView;

  varying vec3 v_normal;
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  void main() {
    gl_Position = projection * modelView * position;
    v_normal = mat3(modelView) * normal;
    v_texcoord = texcoord;
  }
```

to the fragment shader:

```
  precision highp float;

  varying vec3 v_normal;
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
  varying float v_modelId;

  void main() {
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vec3(1, 2, -3));  // arbitrary light direction

    float l = dot(lightDirection, normalize(v_normal)) * .5 + .5;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0,1,0) * l, 1);
  }
```

where it looks like it's dropped --- am I reading this right?

I'll be coding this up shortly, and I'll see if I can use a texture.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The texture is not used inside the shader. The texture is read in Javascript and its values are used to generate the y-value (height) of each vertex. It's a bit easier to see in the second code example (line grid) on that page :

```
  for (let z = 0; z <= gridDepth; ++z) {
    for (let x = 0; x <= gridWidth; ++x) {
      const offset = (z * imgData.width + x) * 4;
      // height 0 to 10
      const height = imgData.data[offset] * 5 / 255; 
      // heightmap value used as y value for vertex
      gridPoints.push(x, height, z);
    }
  }
```

The triangle example essentially does the same thing but does some interpolation of heights so it's a bit harder to identify where it's happening.